# Get entity by type in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have a type which is stored in an `Entity` table.

I want to get all records by type.

My method like this :

```
public void read(Type tablename)
{
    // read data in context by type
}
```

I use this code but it doesn't work :

```
var test = new CmsContext().Set(_tableName);
```

Comment: The `var test = ...` is used withint the `read(Type tablename)` function I suppose? Try to use `var test = new CmsContext().Set(typeof(tableName);`

Comment: your code not working .

Comment: If you try to use a `using` statement: `using(var ctx = new CmsContext())`, do any entities come up when you type ctx. by intellisense? I have there's something very wrong with your entities or I don't understand your problem.

Comment: not different between tour code and my code

Comment: I have a Type (user) and In context I have tabel `user '. I want read All ser by Type value . Type value each time pointer to a table

Comment: Yes but `user` is an entity, so if you can't load that entity from your context, there's must be something wrong with your Entity project. Can you link your model for the user DB and fluent api?

Comment: *Doesn't work*, *not working*. After 42 questions you should know that this is an absolutely inadequate problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Query will not execute until you use it's results, for example, by enumerating them to a list.

```
using System.Linq;

...

using(var ctx = new CmsContext())
{
    var allEntitiesInSet = ctx.Set(_tableName).ToList();
}
```

You can read about "lazy execution" of queries here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You can find it in `System.Linq`. It's an extension method in class `Enumerable`. I've added using statement